# Как записать QString в словарь?

Tags: python, pyqt

ToPlainText возвращает QString, которая в словарь не пишется. Как конвертировать ее в string?

Comment: надо toStdString()

Comment: `QString QTextEdit::toPlainText() const` Возвращает текст редактирования текста как обычный текст. Не надо ничего конвертировать. Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 3):

Обычным преобразованием в строку: `str(someTextEdit.toPlainText())`.

Comment: Продолжает вылетать. Я пробовал раньше, все равно на записи в словарь вылетает

Comment: @РоманПугачев что значит вылетает? Приведите ошибки/наблюдаемое поведение и [mre] в вопросе